# fastest way to get process and upload 42 million rows

Tags: sql, aerospike, nosql

I have a database that links Ip ranges to a location id in another table. Its so large we are trying to make a new solution using aerospike.

The solution we came up with is to use Intervals. Something like this:

Key: 1000000 (int64 of ip Address)
Bin1: default:1 (location id for start of given block)

Bin2: 1234567:2 (First ip in block where location id changes):(locationID)

Bin3: 1345678:3 (second ip in block where location id changes):(locationID)

etc

Using this method we could get the location id from the ip mathmatically while still cutting down on the ammount of rows, and the ammount of server processing time.

I want to do some tests on my Idea but im having a problem converting our current system over.

We have a database that has ranges(eg. 0- 160000) with an associated location id.

The range table has 9,297,631 rows.

A c# script i made executes this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GeoIPRanges 
where (startIpNum BETWEEN 300000000 AND 300000100)
OR (endIpNum BETWEEN 300000000 AND 300000100)
OR (startIpNum <= 300000000 AND endIpNum >= 300000100)
```

That takes about 4 seconds per call. The numbers above are example numbers. You can see they are in blocks of 100. The max ip ammount is 4,294,967,295. Doing this in blocks of 100 lands me with 42,949,672 calls of about 4 seconds each. which takes a very long time. The processing time it takes to format the information into the fashion i want for aerospike is negligible.

Knowing all this information, is there any ideas on how to speed this up.

Comment: Are you moving the data to a new server, or just modifying the data in the tables you have to work with Aerospike?

Comment: keeping the old data, moving the processed data to aerospike on a new server

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS to process and transfer the data between the servers?

Comment: I'll look that up, Im not sure if that will or wont help me.

Comment: If you haven't already considered it, I would recommend using SSIS to handle the migration and augmentation of the data in one fell-swoop.  I'm sure others may have different preferred methods, but I've done very similar migrations/loads/data manipulation via SSIS and it has always been very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Aerospike-loader tool](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-loader). If you can dump your data in a csv file format, the loader can load the data into aerospike. It can read multiple CSV files in parallel and load the data into aerospike in parallel. In the internal benchmarks, on decent hardware, we could load upto 200,000 records per second. Read the docs & examples for details.

Comment: although i sped up my program and its now in working order, this is a valuable answer for the community, so i marked it as answer and gave it +1

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are thinking, but just yesterday I used R to extract some data sets from SQL Server, and it turned out to be MAGNITUDES faster than SQL Server itself.  Do a little research on this methodology, and then try something like this...

```
library(XLConnect)
library(dplyr)
library(RODBC)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=Server_Name;database=DB_Name;trusted_connection=true')

NEEDDATE <- as.Date('8/20/2017',format='%m/%d/%Y')

# DataSet1
DataSet1<-paste("DECLARE @NEEDDATE nvarchar(25)
SET @NEEDDATE = '2017-07-20'

SELECT      . . .

        )")


DataSet1 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, DataSet1)
DataSet2 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, DataSet2)

Combined <- rbind(DataSet1, DataSet2)



ExcelFile <- loadWorkbook("C:/Test/Excel_File.xlsx")


Sheet1=tbl_df(readWorksheet(ExcelFile,sheet="Sheet1"))
Sheet2=tbl_df(readWorksheet(ExcelFile,sheet="Sheet2"))


write.csv(DataSet1, paste0("C:/Test/Output_", NEEDDATE, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```